# Apache Jmeter Graphs

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a question regarding graph for child requests of HTTP request sampler.

I am making a request to home page and including option of request embedded resources.

In response I am getting home page and also some css and js files.

Now I need a way to add graphs for those child requests(css and js files ). In response time graph, I can see only one graph for home page.

Is there a way to add these fields to graph along with home. are there any third party plugins you guys are aware of.

Thanks for your response.

Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I read at http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request,  I believe that when you tell it to request embedded resources, it encapsulates this as part of the request, so the response time you see is the overall response time, and I don't think you can easily do what you want.  That said, you can use various post processors to extract the URLs of the embedded into variables items and then do requests for them individually, though it's a pain.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree there is total response time and also i can see response time of each embedded files in view results listener. I trying to get all those in graph. I Cant figure out how